# Fixing the issue where upon calculating how frequently a function is called during multiprocessing it returns a negative value

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, timing

I have a function `foo()` which might be accessed by multiple worker processes concurrently. This function blocks until an output is ready, and then returns it. A sample `foo` is below:

```
import random
from time import sleep

def foo():
    
    # Mimic blocking of function
    sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
    
    output = 'result of some logic'
    return output
```

I had a need to calculate how frequently (rate) this function is called (For example once every 15 seconds). However, I do not want this calculated rate to include the time spent in the actual function (since `foo` may block for long time). To do this with only 1 worker, I ran this:

```
import random
import time
from time import sleep

call_rate = {'rate': 0.0, 'total_time': 0.0, 'last_call': time.time(), 'total_calls': 0}

def foo():
    global call_rate
    enter_time = time.time()
    # Mimic blocking of function
    sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

    output = 'result of some logic'
    time_waited = time.time() - enter_time

    # Add the time since last function call, and remove time spent inside the function
    call_rate['total_time'] += time.time() - call_rate['last_call'] - time_waited
    call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()
    call_rate['total_calls'] += 1

    # calculate rate
    call_rate['rate'] = call_rate['total_time'] / call_rate['total_calls']
    return output

def worker(num):
    for _ in range(num):
        # Mimic doing some logic before asking output
        sleep(1)

        foo()

worker(3)

# Output: 1.005s . As expected since worker waits 1s before each call
print('foo called once every {}s'.format(call_rate['rate']))
```

Basically, I calculated the total time-differences between consecutive calls, and, after subracting the time spent within the function, divided that by the total number of calls (`rate = total_time / total_calls`)

But when I run this with multiple workers the output is negative:

```
import random
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process


def foo(call_rate):

    enter_time = time.time()
    # Mimic blocking of function
    sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

    output = 'result of some logic'
    time_waited = time.time() - enter_time

    # Add the time since last function call, and remove time spent inside the function
    call_rate['total_time'] += time.time() - call_rate['last_call'] - time_waited
    call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()
    call_rate['total_calls'] += 1

    # calculate rate
    call_rate['rate'] = call_rate['total_time'] / call_rate['total_calls']
    return output

def worker(num, call_rate):
    for _ in range(num):
        # Mimic doing some logic before asking output
        sleep(1)

        foo(call_rate)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a shared dictionary accessible by all processes
    m = Manager()
    call_rate = m.dict({'rate': 0.0, 'total_time': 0.0, 'last_call': time.time(), 'total_calls': 0})
    
    w = []
    
    # Create 3 worker processes that run foo() thrice 
    for i in range(3):
        w.append(Process(target=worker, args=(3, call_rate,)))
        w[i].start()
    for i in range(3):
        w[i].join()
        
    # Output: -0.97s 
    print('foo called once every {}s'.format(call_rate['rate']))
```

I can kind-of understand why the output is negative. Because there are now multiple processes, the time difference between each consecutive function call becomes smaller and smaller and subtracting the time spent wihtin the function of one process doesn't make much sense now because the function calls can now be from different processes. So my question is how can I get the output in the second case as approximately 0.3s (since there are 3 workers calling the method concurrently with 1s delay) without knowing the number of workers running?

**Disclaimer**
I have already asked (a quite crude varient of) this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68144236/timing-how-frequently-a-function-is-called-ignoring-the-time-spent-in-the-functi?noredirect=1#comment120440231_68144236). However, before posting this question, I read the meta discussions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362442/how-do-i-re-ask-a-question) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339624/how-to-ask-same-question-again-on-stack-overflow). The reason I believe this question is not a duplicate of my previous one is because it focuses on a much more smaller, better explained issue rather than then my original question which was much broader and failed to explain itself clearly. My aim at that time was to not only seek an answer for this query, but alternatives in my broader approach itself, which led it to becoming vague and arcane. Unlike previously, I have given reproducible code focused on a single, explicit issue and this question as a whole has more useful applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it without asking for the number of workers running:

```
import random
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, Lock

def foo(call_rate, lock):
    # Shift this to the start of the function
    with lock:
        call_rate['total_time'] += time.time() - call_rate['last_call']
        call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()
        call_rate['total_calls'] += 1
        call_rate['rate'] = call_rate['total_time'] / call_rate['total_calls']
    
    # Mimic blocking of function
    sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

    output = 'result of some logic'


    # By doing this, we are ignoring the time spent within the function
    with lock:
        call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()
    return output

def worker(num, call_rate, lock):
    for _ in range(num):
        # Mimic doing some logic before asking output
        sleep(1)

        foo(call_rate, lock)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a shared dictionary accessible by all processes
    m = Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    call_rate = m.dict({'rate': 0.0, 'total_time': 0.0, 'last_call': time.time(), 'total_calls': 0})

    w = []

    # Create 3 worker processes that run foo() thrice 
    for i in range(3):
        w.append(Process(target=worker, args=(3, call_rate, lock, )))
        w[i].start()
    for i in range(3):
        w[i].join()

    # Output: 0.354s 
    print('foo called once every {}s'.format(call_rate['rate']))
```

I will explain why this works. In the original code, the last call time was recorded AFTER the function had blocked. This meant that the time spent in the function need to be subtracted. But, as @Booboo had already pointed out in the comment to their answer, this was problematic because there maybe multiple workers running and we can't just subtract the waiting time EACH worker spends in the function.

A simple workaround to this is to record the last call time at the start of the function, where the time spent within the function has not yet been added. But it still doesn't solve the broader problem because the next time `foo()` will be called from the worker, it will include the time spent within the function from the last call, leaving us at square one again. But this, and I don't know why I didn't see this before, can be fixed very simply;  by adding this line just before the function exits:

`call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()`

This makes sure that when the function exits, the last call is refreshed such that it seems the worker did not spend any time in the function at all. This approach does not require subtracting anything and thats why it works.

I did a test where I ran this 10 times and calculated some statistics using the code below:

```
import random
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, Lock
import statistics


def foo(call_rate, lock):
    with lock:
        call_rate['total_time'] += time.time() - call_rate['last_call']
        call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()
        call_rate['total_calls'] += 1
        call_rate['rate'] = call_rate['total_time'] / call_rate['total_calls']
    # Mimic blocking of function
    sleep(2)

    output = 'result of some logic'


    # By doing this, we are ignoring the time spent within the function
    with lock:
        call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()
    return output

def worker(num, call_rate, lock):
    for _ in range(num):
        # Mimic doing some logic before asking output
        sleep(1)

        foo(call_rate, lock)

def main():
    # Create a shared dictionary accessible by all processes
    m = Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    call_rate = m.dict({'rate': 0.0, 'total_time': 0.0, 'last_call': time.time(), 'total_calls': 0})

    w = []

    # Create 3 worker processes that run foo() thrice
    for i in range(3):
        w.append(Process(target=worker, args=(3, call_rate, lock, )))
        w[i].start()
    for i in range(3):
        w[i].join()

    return call_rate['rate']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    avgs = []
    for i in range(10):
        avgs.append(main())

    print("Highest is : {}".format(max(avgs)))
    print("Lowest is : {}".format(min(avgs)))
    print("Avergae is : {}".format(statistics.mean(avgs)))
```

This outputs:

```
Highest is : 0.35980285538567436
Lowest is : 0.3536567423078749
Avergae is : 0.356808172331916
```

As a 'proof' that the above code does ignore the time spent within the function, you can make the function block for a larger time, say 15s, and the output will still be approximately the same.

**Update**

The reason why the frequency is not 0.3s when the function blocks for a varying time has to do with when the workers enter and exit `foo()`. Consider the code below where two workers are run once which execute `foo()` twice and output `call_rate` every enter and exit of `foo()` along with a unique id to identify the worker:

```
import random
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, Lock
import statistics
import string

def foo(call_rate, lock, id):
    with lock:
        call_rate['total_time'] += time.time() - call_rate['last_call']
        call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()
        call_rate['total_calls'] += 1
        call_rate['rate'] = call_rate['total_time'] / call_rate['total_calls']
        print("{} entered, call rate {}".format(id, call_rate))
    # Mimic blocking of function
    sleep(1)

    output = 'result of some logic'

    # By doing this, we are ignoring the time spent within the function
    with lock:
        call_rate['last_call'] = time.time()
        print("{} exited, call rate {}".format(id, call_rate))
    return output


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


def worker(num, call_rate, lock):
    id = id_generator()
    for _ in range(num):
        # Mimic doing some logic before asking output
        sleep(1)

        foo(call_rate, lock, id)

def main():
    # Create a shared dictionary accessible by all processes
    m = Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    call_rate = m.dict({'rate': 0.0, 'total_time': 0.0, 'last_call': time.time(), 'total_calls': 0})

    w = []

    # Create 3 worker processes that run foo() thrice
    for i in range(2):
        w.append(Process(target=worker, args=(2, call_rate, lock, )))
        w[i].start()
    for i in range(2):
        w[i].join()

    return call_rate['rate']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    avgs = []
    for i in range(1):
        avgs.append(main())

    print("Highest is : {}".format(max(avgs)))
    print("Lowest is : {}".format(min(avgs)))
    print("Avergae is : {}".format(statistics.mean(avgs)))
```

Note that in this code, foo() always blocks for 1s. The rate should be close to 0.5s since there are two workers present. Running this code:

Output #1:

```
XEC6AU entered, call rate {'rate': 1.1851444244384766, 'total_time': 1.1851444244384766, 'last_call': 1624950732.381014, 'total_calls': 1}
O43FUI entered, call rate {'rate': 0.6178374290466309, 'total_time': 1.2356748580932617, 'last_call': 1624950732.4325447, 'total_calls': 2}
XEC6AU exited, call rate {'rate': 0.6178374290466309, 'total_time': 1.2356748580932617, 'last_call': 1624950733.4327667, 'total_calls': 2}
O43FUI exited, call rate {'rate': 0.6178374290466309, 'total_time': 1.2356748580932617, 'last_call': 1624950733.4484024, 'total_calls': 2}
XEC6AU entered, call rate {'rate': 0.7401185035705566, 'total_time': 2.22035551071167, 'last_call': 1624950734.433083, 'total_calls': 3}
O43FUI entered, call rate {'rate': 0.558994710445404, 'total_time': 2.235978841781616, 'last_call': 1624950734.4487064, 'total_calls': 4}
XEC6AU exited, call rate {'rate': 0.558994710445404, 'total_time': 2.235978841781616, 'last_call': 1624950735.4333804, 'total_calls': 4}
O43FUI exited, call rate {'rate': 0.558994710445404, 'total_time': 2.235978841781616, 'last_call': 1624950735.4958992, 'total_calls': 4}
Highest is : 0.558994710445404
Lowest is : 0.558994710445404
Avergae is : 0.558994710445404
```

The rate is 0.5s, which should be expected. Notice how both the workers enter and exit the functions simultaneously. Now after changing the function blocking time from 1s to `random.randint(1, 10)`, this is what I get:

Output #2

```
NHXAKF entered, call rate {'rate': 1.1722326278686523, 'total_time': 1.1722326278686523, 'last_call': 1624886294.4630196, 'total_calls': 1}
R2DD8H entered, call rate {'rate': 0.5939309597015381, 'total_time': 1.1878619194030762, 'last_call': 1624886294.478649, 'total_calls': 2}
NHXAKF exited, call rate {'rate': 0.5939309597015381, 'total_time': 1.1878619194030762, 'last_call': 1624886300.4648588, 'total_calls': 2}
NHXAKF entered, call rate {'rate': 0.7293914159138998, 'total_time': 2.188174247741699, 'last_call': 1624886301.465171, 'total_calls': 3}
R2DD8H exited, call rate {'rate': 0.7293914159138998, 'total_time': 2.188174247741699, 'last_call': 1624886302.4811018, 'total_calls': 3}
R2DD8H entered, call rate {'rate': 0.7971136569976807, 'total_time': 3.1884546279907227, 'last_call': 1624886303.4813821, 'total_calls': 4}
NHXAKF exited, call rate {'rate': 0.7971136569976807, 'total_time': 3.1884546279907227, 'last_call': 1624886304.4660738, 'total_calls': 4}
R2DD8H exited, call rate {'rate': 0.7971136569976807, 'total_time': 3.1884546279907227, 'last_call': 1624886307.4826, 'total_calls': 4}
Highest is : 0.7971136569976807
Lowest is : 0.7971136569976807
Avergae is : 0.7971136569976807
```

The rate, unlike before, is almost 0.8. Moreover, both workers are no longer entering and exiting the function together either. This is ofcourse due to one blocking for a longer time than the other. But because they are no longer in sync, they are waiting for 1s at separate times instead of together inside of the `worker()` function. You can even see that in the `call_rate['total_time']`. For Output #1, where the workers are in sync, it is ~2s, while for Output #2 it is ~3s. And hence the difference in rates. So the 0.8s is the true rate of the workers calling `foo()` in this scenario, not the assumed 0.5s. Multiplying the rate by the number of processes would miss this nuance.

Comment: What a terrible benchmark. You replaced in `foo`  your call to `sleep(random.randint(1, 3))` with `sleep(2)`. How can you expect any reasonable variance from one run to the next? If you use a random `sleep` value and print out `avgs`, you get: `[0.46814947658114964, 0.46137473318311906, 0.46227243211534286, 0.5757057931688097, 0.4611021677652995, 0.4637126392788357, 0.3502512772878011, 0.4613811704847548, 0.35073762469821507, 0.4606024954054091]` with `Highest is : 0.5757057931688097, Lowest is : 0.3502512772878011, Avergae (Sic) is : 0.45152898099687366`, which are not great results.

Comment: The problem, I believe, arises from your using a common `last_call` value for all your processes.

Comment: I also don't think that in `foo` the last `with lock:` is accomplishing anything important.

Comment: @Booboo check my update. And you're right, the last lock is unecessary

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

For good measure you should probably be ensuring that `foo` is updating the `call_rate` dictionary under a `Lock` instance to handle concurrent access now that you are running multiple processes. But the real problem is that value `last_call` needs to be maintained for *each* process and cannot be shared among the processes.

This solution uses a managed class, `WorkerManager` that is able to keep track of all the created processes as long as  method `init_process` is called for each  process passing its process id *immediately* after it's started as in the code below. Then all a worker function has to do is call method `update_statistics` passing the wait times for each of its requests it is processing. A call to `get_statistics` will return the statistics.

```python
import random
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, Lock, current_process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class WorkerManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._total_calls = 0
        self._total_time = 0.0
        self._rate = 0.0
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._call_times = {}

    def init_process(self, pid):
        self._call_times[pid] = time.time()

    def update_statistics(self, pid, wait_time):
        now = time.time()
        time_elapsed = now - self._call_times[pid]
        execution_time = time_elapsed - wait_time
        self._call_times[pid] = now
        with self._lock:
            self._total_calls += 1
            self._total_time += execution_time
            self._rate = self._total_time / (self._total_calls * len(self._call_times))

    def get_statistics(self):
        return {'rate': self._rate, 'total_time': self._total_time, 'total_calls': self._total_calls}

class WorkerManagerManager(BaseManager):
    pass

WorkerManagerManager.register('WorkerManager', WorkerManager)


def foo(worker_manager):
    enter_time = time.time()
    # Mimic blocking of function
    sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

    output = 'result of some logic'

    wait_time = time.time() - enter_time

    pid = current_process().pid
    worker_manager.update_statistics(pid, wait_time)

    return output

def worker(worker_manager, num):
    for _ in range(num):
        # Mimic doing some logic before asking output
        sleep(1)

        foo(worker_manager)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with WorkerManagerManager() as m:
        worker_manager = m.WorkerManager()
        processes = [Process(target=worker, args=(worker_manager, 3)) for _ in range(3)]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
            worker_manager.init_process(p.pid)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
        statistics = worker_manager.get_statistics()
        print('foo called once every {}s'.format(statistics['rate']))
```

Prints:

```
foo called once every 0.34751895621970846s
```

**How to use a process pool**

And if you want to use a process pool, this is how you might use a pool size of 3 to submit 6 tasks:

```python
import random
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, Lock, current_process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from functools import partial

class WorkerManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._total_calls = 0
        self._total_time = 0.0
        self._rate = 0.0
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._call_times = {}

    def init_process(self, pid):
        self._call_times[pid] = time.time()

    def update_statistics(self, pid, wait_time):
        now = time.time()
        time_elapsed = now - self._call_times[pid]
        execution_time = time_elapsed - wait_time
        self._call_times[pid] = now
        with self._lock:
            self._total_calls += 1
            self._total_time += execution_time
            self._rate = self._total_time / (self._total_calls * len(self._call_times))

    def get_statistics(self):
        return {'rate': self._rate, 'total_time': self._total_time, 'total_calls': self._total_calls}

class WorkerManagerManager(BaseManager):
    pass

WorkerManagerManager.register('WorkerManager', WorkerManager)


def pool_init(worker_manager):
    worker_manager.init_process(current_process().pid)

def foo(worker_manager):
    enter_time = time.time()
    # Mimic blocking of function
    sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

    output = 'result of some logic'

    wait_time = time.time() - enter_time

    pid = current_process().pid
    worker_manager.update_statistics(pid, wait_time)

    return output

def worker(worker_manager, num):
    for _ in range(num):
        # Mimic doing some logic before asking output
        sleep(1)

        foo(worker_manager)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with WorkerManagerManager() as m:
        worker_manager = m.WorkerManager()
        pool = Pool(3, initializer=pool_init, initargs=(worker_manager,))
        # run 6 tasks
        pool.map(partial(worker, worker_manager), range(6))
        statistics = worker_manager.get_statistics()
        print('foo called once every {}s'.format(statistics['rate']))
```

Prints:

```
foo called once every 0.333592324786716s
```

Comment: See my update as to why you *do* need to use locking. As to the second part of your comment, I need to reflect a bit.

Comment: Oh that's weird. The multiprocessing [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) say regarding class Value objects that  "These shared objects will be process and thread-safe.". But apparently they are not?

Comment: Thread-safety is a separate issue. Now if you had a managed `list`, for example, the `append` method is thread-safe and you would not have to lock that. But when you have a *sequence of calls on a managed object* or a single call such as `+=`, which is not atomic, how could there be automatic locking between those calls? There is no way the proxy knows that you are through making your sequence of calls.

Comment: I've updated code in the only way I know to get the results you are looking for. Ideally what you would like to do is over some period of wall time T you would measure how many times `N` `foo` was called. Dividing `T/N` would give you an absolute rate. But you want to subtract from T the wait time. But if you just add up all the wait times it could even exceed T because these `foo` instances are running in parallel and so you need to account for that. It is very problematic.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly it. I'll try to give this problem another go today, otherwise I'll just have to compromise and ask for the number of workers running to calculate the rate like this answer

Comment: I have updated my answer. In another question you posted you had asked why one would want to use a managed class. It creates a clean interface for your user community hiding a lot of the details. Think: **encapsulation**.

Comment: What if the processes die after running foo() a few times? You would need another function to update the length of `_call_times` which the worker calls before terminating. Moreover, simply adjusting the rate based on the number of processes, as I have found, might be a tad bit inaccurate because we only want to ignore the time spent within the function, not the aftermath of the blocking where the functions may no longer be in sync.